# Dojo treemodel- adding large number of items

Tags: dojo, tree

I am trying to add a large number of items (100+) to my tree via ForestStoreModel by calling newItem in a loop.  This seems to be quite slow and locks up the browser.  Is there any way I can do something similar to grid's beginUpdate & endUpdate?  I want to basically 'turn off' my tree, add 100 items in a batch, then 'turn on' my tree.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try detaching the store from the tree, update the model, and then reattach the store.  However, it may be the model that is slow in inserting.

Comment: BTW, why are you adding to many items to a tree dynamically?  You should optimize your code so that you add items only when necessary (e.g. when the user expands a node).

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Chung suggested, the best way would be to only add nodes that the user requires at a specific node level; but sometimes you may have a large number of nodes at the same level or other things might get in the way. In order to update the tree with a large number of items all at once, I would suggest creating a new store/updating your old store, then you need to refresh the tree rendering. So once the store has the correctly formatted array, do this (credit to Layke for the hack [How to update dojo tree data dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409097/how-to-update-dojo-tree-data-dynamically)):

```
            // Completely delete every node from the dijit.Tree     
            myTree._itemNodesMap = {};
            myTree.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
            myTree.model.root.children = null;

            // Destroy the widget
            myTree.rootNode.destroyRecursive();

            // Recreate the model, (with the model again)
            myTree.model.constructor(myTree.model);

            // Rebuild the tree
            myTree.postMixInProperties();
            myTree._load();
```